# Training model ignored by stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, training-data, scoring

I've made a small, sample training model to use when performing sentiment analysis with coreNLP. In order to get coreNLP to use this model, I've written the following lines of code:

```
props = new Properties(); 
props.put("sample_model-0023-100.00.ser.gz", "/home/usr/Documents/coreNLP/");
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, lemma, sentiment"); 
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

However, it doesn't look like the code is using the model I'm pointing to. I know this because I passed a couple of sentences to it that should get certain scores if the code were to use this model, but I'm getting different scores. Am I missing something in my lines of code that's preventing coreNLP from using the model I've created?

Comment: How do you use custom model? I am starting to learn NLP and I am curious about how can we train our custom model. Is there some documentation regarding same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
props.put("sentiment.model", "/path/to/sample_model-0023-100.00.ser.gz");
```

Comment: Thank you, my arguments were messed up.